# artwork missing from US9476133

Tags: patent-search, patent-drawings

In reference to the patent: [US9476133](https://www.google.com/patents/US9476133)

Hi, I am Brian Gilman you can email me at brian@gilmanindustries.com.
I viewed my patent and noticed the artwork was missing. Can your group update the artwork? it is the same as US 20140284209 A1 (https://www.google.com/patents/US20140284209).

Thank you,
Best regards,
Brian Gilman, CEO
Gilman Industries LLC.

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times. Don’t use www.goole.com/patents. Use patents.google.com or www.lens.org.

Comment: @EricShain take the comment and make it an answer. Somewhat trivial, but still, rather a real answer than a comment-answer

Answer (score 1):

For reasons no one can explain, Google provides two different sites for viewing patents [www.google.com/patents](http://www.google.com/patents) and [patents.google.com](http://patents.google.com). Only patents.google.com reliably shows patent figures. I would suggest, however, that you seriously consider using [The Lens](https://www.lens.org/lens/) for patent searching. Here is [US9476133](https://www.lens.org/lens/patent/US_9476133_B2) on The Lens. You'll find the entire PDF with figures. The Lens site provides (in my opinion) more and better tools for patent searching than Google. It is completely non-commercial and you don't need to register or log in. You get some very slick graphical analyses. If you do create an account you gain some useful additional tools like saved searches and collections. In my testing, I've found The Lens to provide more complete searching. Searching for my own patents, for instance, The Lens returns a complete and correct list whereas Google misses patents.